# multiple image Swipe Gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i created images Swipe Gesture that following to this tutorial: [the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOTp3GiegxU)

the image swiper working good but i need your help with  - how to duplicate this code to make more "swipers", with different images. 
there is simple way to make this without codding?

the code is: (viewcontroller.m)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
NSInteger imageindex = 2;

- (IBAction)handleswipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
NSLog( @"swiped");
NSArray *images=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 @"vodkacomp1.jpg",
                 @"vodkacomp2.jpg", nil];

UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction =
[(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

switch (direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
        imageindex++;
        break;
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
        imageindex--;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

imageindex = (imageindex < 0) ? ([images count] -1):
imageindex % [images count];
_vodkacom.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageindex]];    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

the viewcontroller.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *vodkacom;

- (IBAction)handleswipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender;


@end
```

Comment: Just to understand the context of the issue, do you have a UIImageView with a swipe gesture attached to it. Every time a swipe is registered it calls the method above, is this correct

Comment: yes. the swipe take the photos from the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this without coding, but you can use UIScrollView's paging functionality to achieve what you are looking for, Apple has a page of sample code here: [PageControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795).

Comment: hey, thank you for answering. i create one swiper ussing codding that i showed. you can tell me what should i write to make another swiper?

Comment: So, you want to change your code to make it work with multiple images?

Comment: hey, i figure out how to do that and it works perfect. thanks.